# What is the information present inside a kernel core dump

Tags: kernel, core-dump

I am running CentOS 6.

The system got a Kernel Panic and rebooted.

I have enabled coredump generation, hence it generated a Kernel Core Dump of Size 300MB.

What is the information that got captured in this 300MB? Is there a way I can list all the memory segments captured inside? Can I fine tune the information captured?

Answer (score 2):

The Red Hat Crash Utility is a kernel-specific debugger. It is usually used for performing postmortem system analysis when the system panicked, locked up, or appears unresponsive. The utility can be used to investigate:

```
Live Linux systems
Linux kernel core dumps created by the Kdump facility
Compressed Linux kernel core dumps created by the makedumpfile command (from kdump dumpfiles)
Linux kernel core dumps created from by the Red Hat Netdump facility
Linux kernel core dumps created from by the Red Hat Diskdump facility
Compressed Linux kernel core dumps created by the Red Hat Diskdump facility
Xen host Linux kernel core dumps created by the Kdump facility
Xen guest Linux kernel core dumps created by the original xendump facility
Xen guest Linux kernel core dumps created by the ELF-format xendump facility
Xen hypervisor core dumps created by the Kdump facility
KVM guest Linux kernel core dumps created by the virsh dump facility
s390 Linux kernel core dumps created by the IBM standalone core dump facility.
s390x Linux kernel core dumps created by the IBM standalone core dump facility.
Linux kernel core dumps created by the LKCD (Linux Kernel Crash Dumps) Sourceforge project
Linux kernel core dumps created by the Mcore patch offered by Mission Critical Linux
```

http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/

https://web.archive.org/web/20160304173508/http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/15/a-quick-overview-of-linux-kernel-crash-dump-analysis

Comment: Hi Khan, how is the RH Crash Utility related to gdb?

Comment: The gdb command of this utitliy ,  passes its argument to the embedded gdb module. It is useful for executing gdb commands that have the same name as crash commands.

Comment: See man page for crash